# Restrict postgresql's public schema's tables visibility in tableua

Tags: postgresql, schema

My requirement is to display only one particular table or materialised view when user give db_host, db_port, db_name, db_username, and db_password to [tableau](https://www.tableau.com/).

Currently tableau is showing all the tables present default public schema. So I tried to create another schema and another role and keeping that perticular table or materilised view in that new schema.

```
CREATE SCHEMA alok_schema;
CREATE ROLE alok LOGIN PASSWORD 'alok';
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA alok_schema TO alok;
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW alok_schema.mview_alok as SELECT name, location from sometable;
GRANT SELECT ON alok_schema.mview_alok TO alok;
```

I revoked access for this new user on public schema

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA public FROM alok;
```

Now user `alok` is not able to see tables present in `public` schema and he can only see table/view present in `alok_schema` when he try

```
psql -h localhost -U alok db_name
```

But this behaviour is not reflecting in tableau even for new user `alok`. In tableau postgresql user `alok` is still seeing all the tables present in public schema because tableau list up tables names by querying `pg_catalog.pg_namespace` which is system catalog and I guess its not allowed to add row level security policy

```
create policy restrict_rows_for_alok on pg_catalog.pg_namespace to alok using (nspname = alok_schema);
ERROR:  permission denied: "pg_namespace" is a system catalog
```

So either I am seeing all the tables or none of the tables in tableau.

Is there any way I can restrict public schema's table listing in tableau? I want only `mview_alok` to be visible in tableau which is present in schema `alok_schema`.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Could you provide an example of what is in your materialized view that you want to share and what could be in your materialized view that you don't want to share ?